# `PyRun_String` equivalent in Python stable ABI?

Tags: python, c

I have a C++ Python library that I'd like to translate to use the [stable ABI](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/stable.html). It currently uses [`PyRun_String`](https://docs.python.org/3.12/c-api/veryhigh.html#c.PyRun_String)

```cpp
PyRun_String("a = 1", start, globals, locals);
```

which is *not* part of the stable ABI. Is there a useful replacement for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile the string with [`Py_CompileString`](https://docs.python.org/3.12/c-api/veryhigh.html#c.Py_CompileString) and evaluate the resulting code object with [`PyEval_EvalCode`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/veryhigh.html#c.PyEval_EvalCode). Both of those functions are available in the Limited API.

So instead of

```
PyObject *val = PyRun_String("code here", start, globals, locals);
```

you'd do

```
PyObject *codeobj = Py_CompileString("code here", "<string>", start);
if (!codeobj)
{
    // error!
    do_something_about_that();
}
PyObject *val = PyEval_EvalCode(codeobj, globals, locals);
```